# Trying to use INTO...SELECT in MySQL. Having trouble with the WHERE clause.

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm trying to make it so that it copies all the data from oa_tags into member_info, but the problem is that I have a unique auto_increment key in both oa_tags and member_info(it's the same in both, called ID). I need it to copy all the data from oa_tags into member_info, but obviously it has to ignore the entries with the same "ID" column.

This is what I have so far -

```
INSERT INTO member_info
  SELECT *
  FROM oa_tags, member_info WHERE oa_tags.ID > member_info.ID;
```

It's throwing this error at me - "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * INTO member_info FROM oa_tags, member_info WHERE oa_tags.ID > member_info.ID`? Or you can use an `INNER JOIN` as well like so: `SELECT * INTO member_info FROM oa_tags INNER JOIN member_info on oa_tags.ID > member_info.ID`

Comment: Logic fail:   you're selecting from `member_Info` and `oa_tags`.  The column count of 2 tables is going to be greater than that of just `member_info` (the one your inserting into which is part of the select...  but to address the problem, I would need to know table structure of both tables (to ensure they are the same).

Comment: @xQbert Ah, I already tried that(the correct version), and I started trying random things. I already covered the logical things I could think of haha.

Comment: @Elias You can't use the Select * Into with MySQL, it shoots "undeclared variable" errors at you. Insert...Select is the alternative.

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up. I though it was part of the SQL standard, but i guess it is a Microsoft thing.

Comment: No problem. I just wish this darn thing would work.

Comment: What happens if you try to put it into a temp table? replace `INTO member_info` with `INTO #temp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the how mysql supports what you're wanting to do.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

This explains why I wanted to know the field list/structure of both tables.  (I don't like the not in . I think there has to be a way to do it with exists but I'm struggling; and I'm not sure you really care about performance as this seems to be a one time thing)

```
INSERT INTO member_info (FIELD LIST)
    SELECT (FIELD LIST) from oa_tags where ID not in (Select ID from member_info)
```

This might work, but I doubt it and it's far from "Best practice"  but if it's one time throw away, it might get the job done.

```
INSERT INTO member_info 
    SELECT * from oa_tags where ID not in (Select ID from member_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented a best practice where you identify all the columns it will fix many of the problems you are currently having.  In general it is poor practice to use the * for columns other than testing.  Naming/Qualifying your columns (even when there is a lot) will prevent a lot of future issues when tables change.

You can name both the columns in the insert and the select so that they match and only insert the ones you are interested in.  Such as ignoring the 'ID' column

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your column count is off.  Let's assume each table has five columns.

You are trying to insert into member_info which has five columns.  Your select joins both tables which means you will get a total of ten columns in your select.  Run just the select to verify but that is why you are getting the error.

To fix it you can try changing:

```
select *
```

to

```
select oa_tags.*
```

However, I don't believe your current statement will work.  Say you have a row in oa_tags with id 10.  The where clause will match that row to rows in member_info where the id is 1 through 9 and you will end up inserting duplicates.  Also, both tables could have an id of 10 but if member info had an id of 9, that statement would still try to insert id 10.

I would let the auto increment do its job and try:

```
INSERT INTO member_info(column1, column2,... (every column but id)
  SELECT column1, column2,... (every column but id to allow the table to auto increment)
  FROM oa_tags
```

If you don't want to insert every record in oa_tags into member_info, you can still filter on the id by adding:

```
WHERE oa_tags.ID not in (select member_info.ID from member_info);
```